# Looping the scala list in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scala list as below.

```
partList: ListBuffer(2021-10-01, 2021-10-02, 2021-10-03, 2021-10-04, 2021-10-05, 2021-10-06, 2021-10-07, 2021-10-08)
```

Currently Im getting all the data from source into the dataframe based on the above dates.

```
fctExistingDF = ss.read.table(existingTable).filter(s"event_date in ('${partList.mkString("','")}')")
```

Later I'm doing few transformations and loading the data into a delta table. The sample code is as below.

```
fctDF = ss.read.table(existingTable).filter(s"event_date in ('${partList.mkString("','")}')")
    if (fctExistingDF.count() > 0) {
fctDF.createOrReplaceTempView("vw_exist_fct")
val existingRecordsQuery = getExistingRecordsMergeQuery(azUpdateTS,key)
ss.sql(existingRecordsQuery)
.drop("az_insert_ts").drop("az_update_ts")
.withColumn("az_insert_ts", col("new_az_insert_ts"))
.withColumn("az_update_ts", col("new_az_update_ts"))
.drop("new_az_insert_ts").drop("new_az_update_ts")
.select(mrg_tbl_cols(0), mrg_tbl_cols.slice(1,mrg_tbl_cols.length): _*)
.coalesce(72*2)
.write.mode("Append").format("delta")
.insertInto(mergeTable)
mergedDataDF = ss.read.table(mergeTable).coalesce(72*2)

mergedDataDF.coalesce(72)
      .write.mode("Overwrite").format("delta")
      .insertInto(s"${tgtSchema}.${tgtTbl}")
```

The below command in the code is creating a dataframe based on the filter condition on the event_date present in the partList.

```
fctExistingDF = ss.read.table(existingTable).filter(s"event_date in ('${partList.mkString("','")}')")
```

Since it is creating the dataframe with huge data, I want to loop each date in the partlist and read the data into the dataframe, instead of filtering all the dates in the partlist at a time.

I tried below.

```
var counter = 0

while (counter < partList.length) {
  
  fctExistingDF = ss.read.table(existingTable).filter(s"event_date in (I should pass 1st date from the list)
 counter = counter + 1
```

I am new to scala , may be we should use foreach here?
Could someone please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foreach` or `map`, depends whether you want to return the values (`map`) or not (`foreach`):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

partList = List("2021-10-01", "2021-10-02", "2021-10-03", "2021-10-04", "2021-10-05", "2021-10-06", "2021-10-07", "2021-10-08")

partList.foreach { case date =>
   fctExistingDF = ss.read.table(existingTable).filter(col("event_date") === date) 
}
```

If you want to return list of dataframes, use:

```
val dfs = partList.map { case date =>
   fctExistingDF = ss.read.table(existingTable).filter(col("event_date") === date)
```